# I want to hide the dropdown on body click and show on toggle button click

Tags: jquery, toggle, slidetoggle

I am doing the code of hide and show dropdown on click of trigger button and hide on click of body except the trigger button it is working fine.
But it also hides the dropdown if I click on dropdown menu. I don't want  to perform on body click funtion on click of opened dropdown

Please check below code and tell me what i'm doing wrong
Here is my HTML

```
<div class="mhb-item-inner tabletMobile">
<a class="mobile-menu-toggle" href="#"><i class="icon-menu-fine"></i></a>
    <ul id="menu-main-menu-4" class="menu" style="display: block;">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-4667 submenu"><a href=><span>SEARCH HOME</span></a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li class=""><a target="_blank" href=""><span>Search All Homes</span></a></li>
                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-4669"><a target="_blank" href=""><span>Luxury Homes</span></a></li>
            </ul>
            <span class="menu-toggle"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-4677 submenu"><a href="#"><span>SEARCH BY SCHOOL DISTRICT</span></a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-4678"><a target="_blank" href=""><span>Avon Grove</span></a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-4679"><a target="_blank" href=""><span>Coatesville</span></a></li>
                </ul>
                <span class="menu-toggle"></span>
        </li>           
    </ul>
</div>

jQuery(document).click(function(e){
var lernerMenu = jQuery('.tabletMobile .mobile-menu-toggle');
var lernerMenuMenu = jQuery('.tabletMobile .mhb-menu .menu');
if (!lernerMenu.is(e.target) && lernerMenu.has(e.target).length === 0)
{
jQuery('#menu-main-menu-4').hide();
} else {
jQuery('#menu-main-menu-4').show();
}
});
```

It is working fine and hide div on body click but also hides div if I click on opened dropdown I don't want to close dropdown on it's click because it contains sub menus for menu item. I hope it will helps you

Comment: can you post your `html` code.

Comment: I added html please check @AtalPrateek

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery toggle if you want to hide and show based on clicks.. that way you dont need to maintain state using if/else.. Moreover,  assign id to the element you want to toggle rather then accessing using classes..

Comment: But Jquery toggle only hide and show the dropdown on click of toggle button.
If i open dropdown using toggle and click anywhere on body then dropdown not hides.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
jQuery(document).click(function(e){
    var lernerMenu = jQuery('.tabletMobile .mobile-menu-toggle');
    var lernerMenuMenu = jQuery('.tabletMobile .mhb-menu .menu');
    if (!lernerMenu.is(e.target) && lernerMenu.has(e.target).length === 0 && $(e.target).closest('.tabletMobile').length===0){
        jQuery('#menu-main-menu-4').hide();
    } else {
        jQuery('#menu-main-menu-4').show();
    }
});
```